# What does a performance engineer test on a day-to-day basis?

Tags: performance, loadrunner

What are the usual responsibilities for a mid-level employee with 2 to 3 yrs of experience and familiar with a load runner tool?

Comment: what do you expect as an answer ? why do you ask this and in what context ? the answer is too broad and highly subjective depending on the person and team.

Comment: Too many questions you have asked. Can you ask one question with more specific detail?

Comment: I would suggest you break this down into separate questions to make easier to answer.

Comment: I'm currently working as a technical support engineer and want to change profile to performance tester. As I don't have hands on experience in live environment I'm asking these questions. And one more thing I've undergone Load runner tool training in a institute

Answer (score 1):

Your daily routine will be completely dependent on your company and the responsibilities you have in your role.  In simple terms below are some of the potential things in the day to day of a (performance) tester

1. Attend agile ceremonies (standup, look ahead, etc)
2. Evaluate previous performance reports
3. Raise any issues and prioritize accordingly
4. Evaluate areas new test coverage could be implemented
5. Implement new test coverage
6. Document the changes you have made

Comment: If you are an interviewer and want to hire mid-level experience candidate with load runner knowledge. What questions would you ask (I mean technical questions)?

Comment: I partially answered a similar question in http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16116/which-has-value-towards-getting-a-job/16135#16135